# split lines/sentence with over 10 words where the first comma appears

Tags: python, bash, text, split

I have the following code that splits the line every 10 words.

```
    #!/bin/bash

while read line
do
counter=1;
    for word in $line
    do
        echo -n $word" ";
    if (($counter % 10 == 0))
      then
        echo "";
    fi
    let counter=counter+1;
    done
done < input.txt
```

The problem is that the split point is the 10th word. Instead, I want the split point to be the first comma character (only for sentences with over 10 words).

example:

line1: phrase from a test line, which I want to split, and I don't know how.

to

line1: phrase from a test line,
line2: which I want to split, and I don't know how.

If no comma character is found, then simply return the line.

Thanks!

**Edit:** A Python or Bash solution will work.

Comment: Are you looking for a python solution or a bash solution?

Comment: I have removed the `Python` tag until you come back with an answer on how that tag is relevant here or if a Python solution is acceptable.

Comment: Actually, either  bash or python solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to use `awk` and test for 15 or more words and if so, just substitute a `",\n"` for a `", "`, e.g.

```
awk 'NF >= 15 {sub (", ", ",\n")}1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk 'NF >= 15 {sub (", ", ",\n")}1' file
phrase from a test line,
which I want to split, and I don't know how.
```

(if you have a large number of lines, `awk` will be orders-of-magnitude faster than a shell loop)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want to split over `10` words or `15` words.

Simply replace the `10` with `15` in case you are dealing with `15` words.

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NF > 10{ sub(/, */, ",\n", $0); print }' input.txt
```

or more clearly:

```
#! /bin/bash

awk -v OFS=, 'NF > 10{

    # enter this block iff words > 10

    # replace first occurence of , and additional space,
    # if any, with newline
    sub(/, */, ",\n", $0)
    print

}' input.txt
```

Comment: 10/15 close enough, the title and text make that a bit confusing. Great minds think alike. I think our answers hit less than 5 secs apart.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, haha true, I was wondering the same after seeing your answer, although just to be fair, yours is much more precise and shorter, upvoted.

Comment: Both worthy of the UV.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution which check number of word in a string. if number of words in a string are more than 10 then, it will split:

```
output = []
s = 'phrase from a test line, which I want to split, and I dont know how'
while len (s.split()) > 10:
    first_sent,s = s.split(',',1)
    output.append(first_sent)
output.append(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version of the question [for loop in bash simply prints n times the command instead of reiterating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58242977/3220113)

The simple version can be handled with

```
# For each line with 10 words append a newline after the first comma
sed -r '/((\w)+ ){10}/s/,/,\n/' input.txt
```