# for loop in bash simply prints n times the command instead of reiterating

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have a input.txt file with over 6000 lines.

If a line a has over 10 words then I want it to be split but not at the 10th word but where the first comma character appears. And, if the new line also has more than 10 words, then it should also be split, and keep reiterating this process 7 times.

End product: no lines with more than 10 words and commas because they have all been split.

Example:

Input

```
Line 1: This is me, and my sample test line that I like to get working, and I want to be able to kick some ass while doing it
```

Expected output:

```
Line 1: This is me, 
Line 2: and my sample test line that I like to get working,
Line 3: and I want to be able to kick some ass while doing it
```

I'm using the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

for run in {1..7}
do

awk 'NF >= 10 {
sub (", ", ",\n")

}1' input.txt

done
```

This code is not giving the desired result. Instead I get the following output 7 times.

```
line 1: This is me,

line 2: and my sample test line that I like to get working, and I want to be able to kick some ass while doing it.
```

I am leaning to sed, but I'm not clear on something. I see three approaches 1) code reads a line (say line7) and it's over 10 words and breaks it at comma (but doesn't check if the newly broken like is over 10 words) and moves on to the next line. At end of file, it reiterates this process (say 7 times) to ensure that newly broken lines are also under 10 words. THEN, it takes the output of this process and does the same thing but with a new condition (eg. word "and "). THEN, it takes the output of this and so on...I can add endless conditions. This is the approach I prefer. I also think it is easier to code.

Second approach 2) Is that code reads line, and if it's over 10 words it breaks it down at the comma, and then if still over 10 words it breaks that further at the comma and so on until less than 10 words. Only Then, does it move on to the next line. I think this is what Ghoti's code does. But then it's complicated to add additional conditions.
3) 3rd approach is: it breaks the line over 10 words at comma, then remainder line gets broken at "and " and so on. Then in the end, this whole process get reiterated a few time. This is also IMHO not the best way to do it.

Can someone please help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you clean up your sample input and output a little? It's unclear what is really the text we're dealing with. And ... what is the `$run` variable going to be used for? You're executing the `awk` command seven times, but there doesn't seem to be any difference in the seven iterations. How were you imagining the bash for loop would work?

Comment: Why don't you just use gsub instead of sub?

Comment: If you want *awk* to do something seven times, write the for loop in your awk program.

Comment: I don't know prgraming so honestly I don't really understand what you guys are asking me. I've patched this together based on what I read online. Can someone please help do what I need it to do?

Comment: @HenryM, you need not ask a separate question if answer to your previous question doesn't completely solve it. You can simply say that in comments or update existing question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240415/split-lines-sentence-with-over-10-words-where-the-first-comma-appears

Comment: I deleted my post with a `sed` solution. `sed` is fine for replacements in a line. I tried to use it writing logic like a loop, but this will become too complex is this case. I should try to limit the branching construction `:a; .. ; ta` to simple cases.

Comment: @WalterA actually, your sed solution helped a lot. It showed me that I can pipe multiple commands, so i came up with the solution shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what you're after. There are a few problems with your approach:

- awk doesn't process files in-place. So your `sub()` makes a change, `1` prints to stdout, but your input file never changes.
- When you `sub()`, you don't insert a new record into the input stream that awk is processing. Your command merely adds a newline to the current record.

Given these, you *could* get away with processing the input multiple times, as you've suggested. But rather than arbitrarily assuming that you'll have a maximum of seven 10-word phrases on a line, it might be better to actually detect whether you need to continue. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=input.txt
temp=$(mktemp ${input}.XXXX)
trap "rm -f $temp" 0

while awk '
  BEGIN { retval=1 }
  NF >= 10 && /, / {
    sub(/, /, ","ORS)
    retval=0
  }
  1
  END { exit retval }
' "$input" > "$temp"; do
  mv -v $temp $input
done
```

This uses an exit value from awk to determine whether we need to run another iteration of the bash loop. If awk detects that no substitutions were required, then the loop stops.

Comment: Oh wow, I see what you did there. Amazing! Thank you for the help. This is really clever. upvoted.

Comment: Ghoti, quick question...is it possible to make the output a different file instead of overwriting my original document?

Comment: You can make a `temp2` file, add this to the `trap` command and start with `cp $input $temp2`.

Comment: @HenryM .. definitely possible. How would you approach it?

Comment: I would like to add two more conditions to breaking down sentences over 10 words... 1) If no comma characters are found then search the line from left to right for the first "and " (including the space after and so it doesn't split a word like android) and split immediately before "and ". 
2) if no "and " is found, then split the line at exactly after 25 words.  this way it ensure there are no sentences over 10 words.  I think my original approach of doing 7 reiterations of the following conditions is easier to code. the code doesn't need to be elegant or fast as long as it works. any ideas?

Comment: @HenryM ... so ... that's a new set of requirements. I answered your original question, but your updates amount to more than just clarification, you've changed what you want to achieve. StackOverflow is a great tool for getting help with your code, but it's also an awesome resource for people searching for similar solutions to their own problems. Clear questions and answers are the way to do that, If your initial question was answered, you might want to close this question and open a new one for the new requirements.

Comment: @ghoti thanks for help thus far. I did learn quite a lot. from my experience in forums when a new variation of question is required, then a new post should be opened. But in another question I posted I was told to modify to question, so I assumed it worked differently here at SO. I'll open a new post.

Comment: @HenryM, the difference here is that an answer has a value based on its upvotes and whether it's selected as best answer. If you ask a question, people put in time and effort to answer that question. If you then change the question, (or "clarify" it to the point that you're asking something different), you discourage people from answering your future questions, especially if they are complex or involved.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is how I solved this problem. It's ugly, but it works. Plus I can keep piping more sed commands to add more conditions (like my comment above @ghoti).

```
sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' input.txt | sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' | sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' | sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/'| sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' | sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' | sed -r '/((\w)+[., ]+){10}/s/\./\.\n/' | tr -s [:space:] > output.txt
```

Basically, I just piped the same sed command 7 times (in the above sample I'm replacing periods instead of commas, but all the same).
Based on what I read on-line, I'm surprised this command does not allow some of recursive/reiteration. Or if someone knows, please feel free to edit.

Comment: reiteration can be done with `sed :a; something; ta`, repeaing somethng until somethng doesn't find anything to do.

Comment: @WalterA sed -r ':a; /((\w)+[., ]+){9}/s/\./\r\n/; ta' input.txt | tr '\r' '.' ..... this almost worked, except it splits up sentences with less than 10 words when one or more of the words is the word "O.K." or "Dr." or any word that has a period in it. How can we define a word to be anything between white spaces?

Comment: You can include a space in the match with `s/\. /\r\n /;`   and define a word plus boundary with a space like `((\w)+[,.]*[ ]+[,. ]*)` or maybe `((\w[^ ]*)+[ ]+){9}`

Comment: I tried this: sed -r ':a; /((\w[^ ]*)+[ ]+){9}/s/\. /\r\n /; ta' | tr '\r' '.'    and this  sed -r ':a; /((\w)+[,.]*[ ]+[,. ]*)/s/\. /\r\n /; ta' | tr '\r' '.'  both didn't work. Instead they removed all period, except the last, from a line.

Comment: Perhaps ask a new question with good sample input and only ask for command that replaces certain combinations into `===`. Show commands like aove as what you tried. New ideas might contain `\W` or other things  I did not think of.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I'll post another.