# bash find and replace - sed awk

Tags: regex, bash, sed, syntax, escaping

I'm trying to clean up a text file with over 120,000 lines via a bash script. 
I need to perform several find and replaces. The order of each find and replace is important and the file needs to 'remember' the previous find and replaces.

example:
replace all '.'(period) with '.\n' (period and new line), then

replace all '?'(questions marks) with '?\n' (questionmark and new line), then

replace all '!'(period) with '!\n' (exclamation and new line), then...
etc..

I'm doing this, but it's not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/./.\n/g'
sed 's/?/?\n/g'
sed 's/!/!\n/g'
input.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is sed or awk better for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: To use `sed` take a look at the documentation: `man sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may always pipe `sed` commands, but in this case it makes sense to combine all the conditions into one command:

```
sed 's/[.!?]/&\n/g' file > newfile
```

The `[.!?]` matches `.`, `!` or `?` and `&` in the replacement pattern puts the match value back into the string (the newline is added right after this value).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/N0woWp):

```
s="This is a text. Want more? Yes! End"
sed 's/[.!?]/&\n/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
This is a text.
 Want more?
 Yes!
 End
```

If you need to get rid of the spaces after `?`, `!` and `.` use

```
sed 's/\([.!?]\)[[:space:]]*/\1\n/g' file > newfile
```

See [another `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/vyWgQ2). Here:

- `\([.!?]\)` - Capturing group 1: matches `.`, `!` or `?`
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespaces

The `\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured into Group 1.

Comment: Note that using `\n` in the replacement string to get a newline will only work in some versions of `sed`. Specifically, it works in GNU `sed`, but in bsd `sed` it just gets you the letter "n". Presumably OP is using a version where this works, but for anyone else relying on this... it's more complicated in other versions.

Comment: Hey that was really good (also the comment regarding the rid of space...I been googling it for the past 20 mins).  Question though, it important that the code first replaces all the periods in the document before going back through the document and replacing the exclamation marks.     This  is the code I had before your post..........sed -e 's/\./\.\n/g ; s/\!/\!\n/g ; s/\?/\?\n/g ; s/\;/\;\n/g ; s/\n\n\n/\n/g ; s/\n\n/\n/g ; s/\n /\n/g ' input.txt > zz.txt     .....s/\n\n\n/\n/g; s/\n\n/\n/g (tries clean empty new lines); s/\n /\n/g (tries to remove spaces, but doesnt work).

Comment: @HenryM I do not see the point. Please explain in the question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @HenryM Why is it important that it replaces characters one at a time instead of all in one pass? It should give the same result either way.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm trying to clean up a file with find and replace, and the order which command is executed makes a huge difference. Basically, I'm trying to solve this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242977/for-loop-in-bash-simply-prints-n-times-the-command-instead-of-reiterating

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the idea of piping sed commands. It actually led me to solving the problem (although ugly) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242977/for-loop-in-bash-simply-prints-n-times-the-command-instead-of-reiterating